# How to prevent cucumber from hatching several SpringBoot context

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, spring-cache

I am using **Cucumber** + **Spring Boot** + **Spring Cache**

Every time Cucumber jumps from one Scenario Outline to the other, my Spring Boot context is rebuilt (I can see the Banner) and my Spring Cache is rebuild... which takes a lot of time.

I tried to add *@DirtiesContext* above the *@SpringBootTest(Web)* on the java steps class, that didn't helped.

How can I prevent Cucumber from refreshing the context on each and every Scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Cucumber to v5 and make sure you do not have `@DirtiesContext` any where in your spring configuration.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/spring